# VBA Code Does Not Work When Ran?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy an area of information and special paste the values.  By changing the specific cell value at the end of the for loop, I am also changing the information that comes in the area around it.  Therefore, I am attempting to loop through this 462 times and special paste each area on a different worksheet, and each area would be pasted on the row that is below what was previously pasted (starting at row 2).  However, when I actually run the program, absolutely nothing happens.  Can anyone help with this?

Thanks so much, the code is pasted below:

```
Sub timeToLoop()
Dim currentVal As Integer, count As Integer, countStr As String, i As Integer
count = 1
    For i = 1 To i = 462
        count = count + 1
        countStr = CStr(count)
        currentVal = Range("V34").Value
        Worksheets("Query_Tab").Range("V34:BQ34").Copy
            With Worksheets("Compiled")
                .Range(.Cells(countStr, "A"), _
                   .Cells(countStr, "AV")).PasteSpecial xlValues
            End With
        Worksheets("Query_Tab").Range("V34").Value = currentVal + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use numbers in `.Cells()` ? ok its possible, but more for `.Range()`... And if `Count` is equal to i+1 at all times, no need to use two variables.

Comment: To Copy a value, no need to copy/paste. A Simple `SheetB.RangeB.value = SheetA.RangeA.Value` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is at the For loop, it should be:

```
For i = 1 To 462
```

There are other minor issues/tips.

- Row/Column counters are of type **Long**
- No need to use `countStr`
- Depends on Formatting of **V34:BQ34**, you can just assign a destination Range after the `Range("V34:BQ34").Copy`, e.g. `Range("A1:A10").Copy Range("B1:B10")`
- You can use string concatenation within the Range() method. e.g. `Range("A" & count & ":" & "AV" & count)`

Comment: Yep. The statement `i = 462` evaluates to `False`, which gets cast to 0 and makes the loop evaluate to `For i = 1 To 0`. You can verify this by adding `Step -1` - the loop will execute twice.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a reference

> currentVal = Range("V34").Value

Should Refer to

> currentVal = Worksheets("Query_Tab").Range("V34").Value

I agree with Patrick.  You really over-complicated things.

```
Sub timeToLoop()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim currentVal As Integer, i As Integer
    With Worksheets("Query_Tab")

        For i = 2 To 463
            currentVal = .Range("V34").Value

            .Range("V34:BQ34").Copy Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A" & i & ":" & "AV" & i)

            .Range("V34").Value = currentVal + 1
        Next i

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You should watch as many of WiseOwlsTutorials as you can on YouTube.  Here's one on [Ranges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=5).  I would also recommend [Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp) it's a free download that will indent your code for you.